# Trouble importing a C function into Haskell

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I have a C program that calls a Haskell function. I want the Haskell function to be responsible for determining the size of the array (pointer) so I also want Haskell to malloc the pointer from C. I get an error when `malloc_` is called in Haskell. I am not sure how to emulate the way `malloc_` is called in C `malloc_((void *)&ints,sizeof(int),10);` into Haskell.

#### aux.c

```
void malloc_ (void **p, size_t size, int m) {
  *p = malloc(size*m);
}
```

#### main.c

```
int *ints;
// want to call this function in Haskell, C doesn't know how large the array is
// malloc_((void *)&ints,sizeof(int),10);

int ints_size = setIntArray(ints);

for (int i = 0; i < ints_size; i++) {
  printf("ints[%d]: %d\n", i, ints[i]);
}
```

#### Arrays.hs

```
#include "aux.h"
-- this might be wrong
foreign import ccall "malloc_" malloc_ :: Ptr (Ptr ()) -> CSize -> CInt -> IO ()

foreign export ccall "setIntArray" setIntArray :: Ptr CInt -> IO CInt
setIntArray :: Ptr CInt -> IO (CInt)
setIntArray is =  do
  let r = 10 :: Int

  -- if I remove this and malloc in C then it is fine
  malloc_ (castPtr is) (fromIntegral $ sizeOf is) (fromIntegral r)


  x <- addArrayElement r 0

  return $ fromIntegral x

  where
    addArrayElement :: Int -> Int -> IO Int
    addArrayElement r pointerCounter =
      case pointerCounter >= r of
        True  -> return r
        False -> do
          let x = 1234
          poke (advancePtr is pointerCounter) (x :: CInt)
          addArrayElement r (pointerCounter + 1)
```

Comment: Your C code in `main.c` is already wrong for what you want to do, since `setIntArray(ints)` cannot modify the value of `ints` itself, which it would need to do to have `ints` point to allocated memory after the call. Maybe you wanted to call `setIntArray(&ints)`, with `setIntArray` of type `Ptr (Ptr CInt) -> IO CInt`?

Comment: Hmm, my code works fine if I do `malloc_` in C and not Haskell and modifies the values. `ints` is already a pointer. If I am not mistaken the appropriate syntax should be `setIntArray(ints)`, just double checked, if I `setIntArrays(&ints)` it gets a segmentation fault. I don't think it needs to be a double pointer, it is just 1D array being set.

Comment: But you had to pass `&ints` into `malloc_`, so that `malloc_` could change the value of `ints`... the same will be true of `setIntArray`, if you want to move the allocation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the other issues with your question, and just addressing the part about calling `malloc`: you have a few options.

- `malloc` is already imported for you as [malloc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:malloc), or you can even use [mallocArray](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v:mallocArray) in this case.
- If you really want to import `malloc` yourself (maybe you actually want to use a different allocator), you'd make things more convenient for yourself by just returning the pointer value from your wrapper, like `malloc` itself does:

  ```
  void *malloc_ (size_t size, int m) {
    return malloc(size*m);
  }
  ```

  then `foreign import ccall "malloc_" malloc_ :: CSize -> CInt -> IO (Ptr ())`, and just call it.
- If you really want to use this out-argument-style `void malloc_ (void **p, size_t size, int m)`, then you have to allocate storage for a `void *`, so that you can pass its address as the first argument of `malloc_`, like you would do in C.

  ```
    my_allocated_pointer <- with nullPtr $ \pp -> do
      malloc_ pp (fromIntegral $ sizeOf (undefined :: CInt)) (fromIntegral 10)
      peek pp
  ```

  (This is now starting to get a bit silly, since [with](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Utils.html#v:with) uses `malloc` internally... but it's the approach you would use in general.)

Comment: The problem I was trying to solve is that I didn't see a way to allocate memory via the provided functions `malloc` or `mallocArray` and then mutate `is` to equal the memory I allocated. That's why I came up with importing `malloc_`. I don't fully understand `with`.

Comment: You can't do that regardless of `malloc_` or anything else because your C type for `setIntArray` is wrong. That's what I was trying to explain in my comments. Just try writing the whole program in C with the allocation inside `setIntArray` and you will see the problem.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean about `setInArray` being wrong.